# Select SQL Duplicate Data

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables, `Payment` (with 28 columns) and `Users`.

In the `Payment` table, I have a `CreatedBy` column which is taken from the `Users` table.

Here's the code:

```
select 
    *, 
    users.Userid 
from 
    payment 
left join 
    users on users.Userid = payment.CreatedBy 
where 
    payment.PatientInvoiceID = ${id}
    and payment.DeletedBy is null
```

I just need to get `Name` from `Users` table into the `Payment` table so I can get the name of the user. But the data is duplicated into 59 columns.

Can anyone help me? I'm sorry if my English is bad.

Comment: I've removed the `database` tag, because you don't want to know about databases in general. Your question is about how to change your query. (Nigel Ren has removed the `php` tag for the same reason.) So, tagging your request with `sql` is almost all that is needed here. What is missing, though, is what DBMS you are using. E.g. `mysql` or `sql-server` or `oracle`.

Comment: edited my question also. thanks for helping me sir

Comment: I sincerely hope `${id}` isn't doing SQL injection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want

```
select payment.*, users.Userid 
...
```

The asterix means "all". `select *` means all columns, and as you join two tables, this is all columns of the two tables. `select payment.*` means all columns of the payment table.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
  payment.*, 
  users.Userid 
from 
  payment 
  left join users on users.Userid = payment.CreatedBy 
where 
  payment.PatientInvoiceID = ${id}
  and payment.DeletedBy is null
```

> mysql usual specify field，don't use *